# How to manually specified the next view id for a particular direction in android?

Tags: android, view, focus, viewgroup

what is the method or config for manually specified the next view for a particular direction in android?

For Example I have three buttons:

`button1` `button2` `button3`

Normally, when I click right direction, I want to change focus from `button1` to `button2`, then `button3`, but if I have a strange requirement:I want to change focus from `button1` to `button3`, then chage to `button2`.

A more common requirement is that when the focus is in `button3`, I want change focus to `button1` when right direction is clicked!

how can I meet these requirement?

Comment: in the `onCreate` get the view references of all the buttons u need and store them in an array. Then you can loop through the array and change the focus

Comment: @Panther Do I have more easy way? I remember c# have a attribute called `tabindex` can control the order when `TAB` is pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try android view's nextFocusRight/Left/Up/Down properties?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nextFocusRight="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nextFocusRight="@id/button1" />
```

You can set these properties in Java code.

```
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    button3.setNextFocusRightId(R.id.button1);
```